# Add data to CSV if string is not found

Tags: c#

I have an application that updates data within a CSV. What I am trying to add is, if the "name" is not in the CSV, then add it. I have tried changing the `while` to an `if/then`, but that gave me no results, just a blank line within the CSV.

**Code:**

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Split(',')[0].Equals("newName"))
        {
            String[] split = line.Split(',');
            split[1] = tPoints.ToString();
            line = String.Join(",", split);
        }
        lines.Add(line);
    }
}
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path))
{
    foreach (String line in lines)
        writer.WriteLine(line);
}
```

**Current CSV Data:**

```
name,734937
```

If item is NOT found, I am trying have it add a new row. So expected result would be something similar to below:

```
name,734937
newName,0
```

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do here. How does `tPoints` fit? And you say you want this if `"name"` is not in the CSV data, but this sets the value when it IS in the CSV data. Try posting a short except of the sample data and what you'd like for a result.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn tPoints is just data I am adding to the CSV. Yes, the current code is only if "name" is in the CSV. My question is, how can I add it if its NOT in the CSV.

Comment: In any row? Again: sample data and result.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn i have updated post for what I think you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
bool termFound = false;
string searchTerm = "newName";
var lines = new List<string>();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("input.csv"))
{
    string line;

    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        lines.Add(line);

        if (line.Split(',')[0].Equals(searchTerm))
            termFound = true;
    }
}
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("output.csv"))
{
    foreach (string line in lines)
        writer.WriteLine(line);

    if(termFound == false)
        writer.WriteLine($"{searchTerm},0");
}
```